# How do I adjust a ScrollPane to make one of its child Nodes visible within the viewport?

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I am trying to figure out how to scroll a `ScrollPane` such that any `Node` nested within its content can be made visible. The target `Node` may have many levels of nesting that I cannot predict.

This is about as close as I have been able to get. It works, but it's quite a hack and has a bug that produces an endless recursive call loop under certain conditions. There has to be a better way.

```
private void ensureVisible(ScrollPane scrollPane, Node node) {

    Bounds viewportBounds = scrollPane.localToScene(scrollPane.getBoundsInLocal());
    Bounds nodeBounds = node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal());

    if (!viewportBounds.contains(nodeBounds)) {
        if (nodeBounds.getMaxY() > viewportBounds.getMaxY()) {
            // node is below of viewport
            scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVvalue() + 0.01);

            if (scrollPane.getVvalue() != 1.0) {
                ensureVisible(scrollPane, node);
            }
        } else if (nodeBounds.getMinY() < viewportBounds.getMinY()) {
            // node is above of viewport
            scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVvalue() - 0.01);

            if (scrollPane.getVvalue() != 0.0) {
                ensureVisible(scrollPane, node);
            }
        } else if (nodeBounds.getMaxX() > viewportBounds.getMaxX()) {
            // node is right of viewport
            scrollPane.setHvalue(scrollPane.getHvalue() + 0.01);

            if (scrollPane.getHvalue() != 1.0) {
                ensureVisible(scrollPane, node);
            }
        } else if (nodeBounds.getMinX() < viewportBounds.getMinX()) {
            // node is left of viewport
            scrollPane.setHvalue(scrollPane.getHvalue() - 0.01);

            if (scrollPane.getHvalue() != 0.0) {
                ensureVisible(scrollPane, node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just transform the coordinates form the coordinate system of the `Node` to the coordinate system of the content. Based on the content size, viewport size and the transformed coordinates you can determine the scroll position:

```
public static void scrollTo(ScrollPane scrollPane, Node node) {
    final Node content = scrollPane.getContent();
    Bounds localBounds = node.getBoundsInLocal();
    Point2D position = new Point2D(localBounds.getMinX(), localBounds.getMinY());

    // transform to content coordinates
    while (node != content) {
        position = node.localToParent(position);
        node = node.getParent();
    }

    final Bounds viewportBounds = scrollPane.getViewportBounds();
    final Bounds contentBounds = content.getBoundsInLocal();

    scrollPane.setHvalue(position.getX() / (contentBounds.getWidth() - viewportBounds.getWidth()));
    scrollPane.setVvalue(position.getY() / (contentBounds.getHeight() - viewportBounds.getHeight()));
}
```